# Java EE: Sharing entity classes between server and clients

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb, jpa-2.0

I am responsible for a Java EE application that provides backend functionality to a number of clients. Some of the clients are also written in Java, so I have extracted my entities into a separate jar, which server and clients share.

The server uses JPA2 for persistence, JAX-RS for communication with clients and JAXB for serialisation to/from XML and JSON. As a result, the (shared) class files contain both JPA- and JAXB-annotations.

Obviously, the same object behaves differently on the server (where it is a managed JPA entity) and on a client (where it is a de-serialized POJO) - especially with regards to one-to-many relationships.

**Question:** Sometimes I'd like to have individual methodcalls behave differently depending on where they are executed. Can I solve this through inheritance, so that I don't have to manually maintain two implementations of the same classes?

Example:

- A team has many players. A player has a name.
- Requests are mapped to `GET /team/<id>` to get a Team, and `GET /team/<id>/<playerName>` to get a particular player for a team.
- For marshalling and serialisation, the `Team` shall remain "flat" (don't include players). However, include their names in the serialisation so that the clients know which players they can retrieve in detail.

On the server side, I'd build it like this:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Team {

  /* some other fields, belonging to the Team */

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="team")
  @XmlTransient  // don't marshall the players
  List<Player> players;

  /* getters and setters as necessary */

  @XmlElement
  public List<String> getPlayerNames() {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Player p : getPlayers()) {
      names.add(p.getName());
    }
    return names;
  }
}
```

On the client side, I'd map it to:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Team {

  /* some other fields, belonging to the Team */

  List<String> playerNames;

  public List<String> getPlayerNames() {
    return playerNames;
  }

  public void setPlayerNames(List<String> playerNames) {
    this.playerNames = playerNames;
  }

  /* getters and setters as necessary */

}
```

This way, the playernames get marshalled (through `@XmlElement`-annotated `getPlayerNames()`) on the server side. When the client receives it, it unmarshalls the list properly. Everybody is happy.

However, now I'd have to maintain two essentially identical classes, where only minor differences occur... What is the best way to do this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Directly serializing entities and transmitting them over the wire may pose a problem, for example if you have circular references or if you like to include additional information which might be needed for deserialization, especially in JSON. Another issue might be detached entities (If you send them to the client, the entity manager loses control of the entities and you have to reattach them when they come back) or lazy load (you can't lazy load on the client). Therefore I would recommend to convert the entities into Data Transfer Objects before you transmit them over the wire. See Fowler's book Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (page 401, most of the chapter is available through Google Books) for details and motivation.

Using the same classes on the client and server might be problematic too because they behave differently and might diverge further in the future. You might restrict yourself to much by committing to an identical code base on the client and server or end up with a big mess.

Comment: Thanks. Of course the entities are detached, exchanging only representaton is the nature of JAX-RS. As such the entities *are* already DTOs. And, yes, the same class behaves differently on client and server in few cases - the core of my question is how to organize the classes better. Could you provide a suggestion?

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer was to point out I'm against using entities as DTOs. I would use separate classes. But that just as a side note in case I wasn't clear enough. Regarding class organisation if you want to share some common behaviour on the client and server: Create a base class in package A, extend it in package A.S for the server and A.C for the client. Then bundle A + A.S in the same JAR for the server and A + A.C for the client. A Maven multimodule project (one module for A, one module for A.C with A as dependency and one for A.S with A as dependency) might help.

Comment: Thanks @aha for the idea of Maven Multi Module Project... That's the key words I've been looking for weeks now.